# How to select and remove code from multiple lines at once in Python IDE?

Tags: python, ide, editor, selection

I want to delete parts of code which aren't inline. For example, if I have this code:

```
arr1 = np.zeros(3,3)
arr2 = np.zeros(3,3)
arr3 = np.zeros(3,3)
```

And I want to select all the zeros and change them to ones:

```
arr1 = np.ones(3,3)
arr2 = np.ones(3,3)
arr3 = np.ones(3,3)
```

Or selecting only "arr" in all lines and changing them:

```
array1 = np.ones(3,3)
array2 = np.ones(3,3)
array3 = np.ones(3,3)
```

Is it possible in any Python IDE?

Edit: I use Spyder, but I assumed there's a universal way of doing what I described in various IDEs as it's really useful. I saw TheCodingTrain selecting multiple variables and typing new names for them all at once, which is exactly what I want to learn how to do. Rather than selecting one long line, I select multiple line beginnings and edit them all at once.

Comment: which python IDE are you using ??

Comment: Have you tried anything? Such as the common `Ctrl+d` or holding `Ctrl` while pressing multiple words?

Comment: Sublime Text definitely had this capability since I use it quite often, but I’m sure many others will too like Atom

Comment: Its a matter of simple find and replace - depending on your IDE the shortcut changes and unless you are using a minimal IDE you should have access to this. Also I agree with @NChauhan, if you have an option of choosing/changing your IDE take a look at Sublime Text

Comment: any IDE with find and replace option will do.

Comment: @casualcoder I agree there. Even the basic python IDLE has a find and replace function that supports regex too.

Comment: Perhaps you could start by reading your ide documentation ? If it doesn't have a search/replace function then it's not worth a dime...

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in Pycharm. Just hold on the `option` key and select them.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!